# Calling a hashtable with a string in C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

As you can see I have and hashtable that is called by `GetEdinburgh()`
but this programs needs to run mutable times and each time it needs to call a diffrent hashtable. how do I replace the `GetEdinburgh()` with a string like `GetTown()`?

```
static Hashtable GetEdinburgh()
{
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable.Add("Aberdeen", 129);
    hashtable.Add("Ayr", 79);
    hashtable.Add("Fort_William", 131);
    hashtable.Add("Glasgow", 43);
    hashtable.Add("Inverness", 154);
    hashtable.Add("St_Andrews", 50);
    hashtable.Add("Stirling", 36);
    return hashtable;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int total = 1000;
    string Town = "";

    Hashtable hashtable = GetEdinburgh(); //how can I change this to a string?
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(entry.Value) < total)
        {
            total = Convert.ToInt32(entry.Value);
            Town = entry.Key.ToString();
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(Town + ", " + total + "km");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I might have not been specific about my problem. The current code above works fine but I need to expand it. I need to call more hash tables than the supplied one above but I cant call it directly. I need to have a string value that changes each time the a loop is implemented to call a new Table. But I cant convert a `system.Collections.hashtable` to string.

Comment: Do you have a file (or database) with that information?

Comment: you are not clear on your problem, how about describing your desired input->output and method.

Comment: I can see in your code that you are only displaying the town that has the lowest `km`. Is this what you're trying to do? And be more clear about the `GetTown()` you mentioned.

Comment: Please use a `Dictionary<string, int>` if you possibly can.

Comment: Do you mean multiple or mutable, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Felix K. Please note that [the homework tag is deprecated and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can write a method like this:

```
static Hashtable GetHashtable(string Table )
    {
        Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
           switch(table)
          {
        case "Edinburgh":
        hashtable.Add("Aberdeen", 129);
        hashtable.Add("Ayr", 79);
        hashtable.Add("Fort_William", 131);
        hashtable.Add("Glasgow", 43);
        hashtable.Add("Inverness", 154);
        hashtable.Add("St_Andrews", 50);
        hashtable.Add("Stirling", 36);
        break;
           ................
        return hashtable;
    }
```

and you can pass the string to the method and get the values.

> > > > > Click answered if the answer really answers your question..

Comment: I think you miss understood my question. I can get the information out of the hash table fine. but I need to call other hashtables without saying getEndeburg() or GetAberdeen(). I am looking for something like string Hastablename = getEndeburg() and then use the string to call the the hastable. like  Hashtable hashtable = Hashtablename, the problem is that you cant convert a string to a system.object hashtable

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**

Even more simply, if you want to get the matching value from a [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) using a `string` key do this,

```
Hashtable distancesFromEdinburgh = GetEdinburgh();
string town = "Ayr";
int distanceFromEdinburghToAyr = distancesFromEdinburgh[town];
```

**EDIT**

The answer is the very simplest, and worst way is,

```
static HashTable GetTown(string town)
{
    Hashtable hashtable;

    switch(town)
    {
        case "Edinburgh":
            hashtable = new Hashtable();
            hashtable.Add("Aberdeen", 129);
            hashtable.Add("Ayr", 79);
            hashtable.Add("Fort_William", 131);
            hashtable.Add("Glasgow", 43);
            hashtable.Add("Inverness", 154);
            hashtable.Add("St_Andrews", 50);
            hashtable.Add("Stirling", 36);
            break;

            // Other cases here
    }

    return hashtable;
}
```

---

Ok, don't use `HashTable` for a start. The code below uses a number of up to date features and has equivalent functionality to your posted code.

What is the question again?

```
private enum Towns
{
    Aberdeen,
    Ayr,
    FortWilliam,
    Glasgow,
    ...
}

private static IDictionary<Towns, int> GetEdinburgh()
{
    return new Dictionary
    {
        { Key = Aberdeen, Value = 129 },
        { Key = Ayr, Value = 79 },
        { Key = FortWilliam, Value = 131 },
        { Key = Glasgow, Value = 43 },
        ...
    };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var closest = this.GetEdinburgh()
        .Where(p => p.Value < 1000)
        .Min(p => p.Value);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}km", closest.Key, closest.Value);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

If you want a common get town function you could declare it like this.

```
private static IDictionary<Towns, int> GetTown(Towns town)
{
    switch(town)
    {
        case Towns.Edinburgh:
            return new Dictionary
            {
                { Key = Aberdeen, Value = 129 },
                { Key = Ayr, Value = 79 },
                { Key = FortWilliam, Value = 131 },
                { Key = Glasgow, Value = 43 },
                ...
            }

        case Towns.Ayr
            ...

        ...

        default:
           throw new ArgumentException(
               string.Format("{0} not implemented", town),
               "town"); 
    };
}
```

This implementation of this function would differ depending on how you store or define the distances. The current implementation assumes they are hardcoded which would be fast but a little brittle to maintain.

If you have the coordinates of the towns locations you could calculate the distance between them, "as the crow flies" on each call.

If you want to generate a "real" best travel distance you need a map and a rather more complicated path finding algorithm.

What have you got, what do you want to do?

Comment: I have to create a search algorithm that find the closest town and then moves to that town to find his closest town (cant move to same town twice.) the code above moves to the first town but then I need to call a new hashtable /or array to bring the new information up. But I cant call it directly that is why I asked how to call an hashtable with a string.

Comment: @user1752505 if you can ask a clear question I can answer it.